# Move files from laptop without usable screen?

Tags: mac, macbook, file-transfer

A friend of mine has an older macbook that has a broken screen, and they've since bought a new macbook. I think I've read somewhere (but I could be wrong, I read A LOT of things online) that there is some way to connect one to the other and have one be almost like another harddrive to the new macbook, so I could move picture files and such off.

I've never really used a mac other than for photoshop when I was in highschool, but is this possible? If not, what's the best way I could move photos and other files off her old macbook and put it on her new one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd use [target disk mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Target_Disk_Mode) - you'd need firewire on both macs, boot up the broken mac while holding the T key and it'll appear to be a firewire disk.

You might also consider just plugging in a screen and doing things the regular way if its a firewire-less mac.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't remember what is was called as it's never really been an issue. If I plugged in a monitor, would it automatically use it?

Comment: I'm not sure, unfortunately. I'm not a mac user, this just happens to be a feature i REALLY wish regular PCs had ;p